# Parent product id of a product using Magento soap v2 api

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, orders, api, soap

I am using Magento SOAP V2 api to access sales order info using soap client implemented in java. Is there a way to get the parent item id of a item ordered. Simply I want to get the configurable product associated with the simple product.